# I am new at developing plugins with a visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

> Error: Unknown property 'SCMC__AP_Voucher__cStandardController.line'

I cannot figure out what is causing the above error message when I attempt to save this record. Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Any suggestions on how to trouble shoot these type of error messages?

```
<apex:page standardController= "SCMC__AP_Voucher__c"
 contentType="application/json;charset=UTF-8" >
    <apex:variable var="payable" value="{!SCMC__AP_Voucher__c}"/>
    <ffps_scmp:mappingDescription >
        <ffps_scmp:mappingHeader targetObject="c2g__codaPurchaseInvoice__c">
            <ffps_scmp:mapping sourceId="{!SCMC__AP_Voucher__c.Id}">
                <ffps_scmp:mappingItem source="{!SCMC__AP_Voucher__c.SCMC__Purchase_Order__c}" 
                target="PO_Number__c"/>,
                </ffps_scmp:mapping>
        </ffps_scmp:mappingHeader>
                <ffps_scmp:relatedMappings >
            <ffps_scmp:relatedMapping relatedObject="c2g__codaPurchaseInvoiceLineItem__c"
            >               
                <ffps_scmp:relatedList var="line" 
                    list="{!line.SCMC__AP_Voucher_Line__r}">                   
                    <ffps_scmp:mapping sourceId="{!line.Id}"
                    >                        
                    <ffps_scmp:mappingItem 
                    source="{!line.SCMC__Purchase_Order_Line_Item__r.SCMC__Item_Master__r.SCMC__Product_Group__r.SCMC__Revenue_Category__c }" 
                            target="c2g__Dimension1__c" />
                        </ffps_scmp:mapping>
                </ffps_scmp:relatedList>
            </ffps_scmp:relatedMapping>
        </ffps_scmp:relatedMappings>            
    </ffps_scmp:mappingDescription>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete, but it's apparent that the most likely cause of the error starts with:

```
<ffps_scmp:mapping sourceId="{!line.Id}"
```

You can't define variables using custom components, so Visualforce doesn't know anything about the "line" variable. Since this appears to be a component from a managed package, you may need to contact the provider or check the documentation for the correct use of this element.